# WCF Reliable Messaging: stuttering service after maxPendingChannels increase

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, ws-reliablemessaging

We have an issue whereby during load testing if we fire calls rapidly at one of our services we were getting the error

"System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException: The request to create a reliable session has been refused by the RM Destination. Server 'net.tcp://localhost:10511/ParameterMonitorService' is too busy to process this request. Try again later. The channel could not be opened."

We increased the value of maxPendingChannels from its default of 4 to 128 and then beyond, and the error has disappeared, now however, rather than throwing the exception the service will just stop processing messages under load and then begin again several minutes later.

It does not seem to drop anything, it just hangs for a while. The more we pound the service the longer this recovery seems to take.

The service is configured as Per-Call with ConcurrencyMode Multiple. Other behavior settings are:

```
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100" maxConcurrentInstances="100"/>

<customBinding>

    <binding name="Services_Custom_Binding" openTimeout="00:00:20" sendTimeout="00:01:00">          
        <reliableSession  ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" maxPendingChannels="128" flowControlEnabled="true" />
        <binaryMessageEncoding>
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />            
        </binaryMessageEncoding>
        <tcpTransport maxPendingConnections="100" listenBacklog="100" />          
      </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

We are kind of stuck. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic performance tuning story. By reconfiguring the throttle on reliable sessions you have removed what used to be the bottleneck in the system, and have moved the bottleneck to somewhere else in your system.

You really can't expect people to pluck a diagnosis of where the bottleneck now lies out of thin air, without any details of how your service is hosted, on what hardware, what it is doing, or how it goes about doing it. You need to instrument your system as comprehensively as you can, using Windows Performance Monitor counters, and interpret these to get an idea of where resource contention is now happening in the system.

My first guess would be that the increased concurrency after removing the session throttle is causing contention for managed thread pool threads, but this is only a guess - really you want to base diagnosis on evidence, not guesswork.

Comment: The problem is repeatable in any of our environments, that includes running on local developers laptops or server environments running on top of VMware. It occours when even reliable messaging is turned off: instead of getting reliable messaging errors, we get a more general netTCP socket error. We are now looking at perfmon but nothing obvious has yet stood out.

Comment: Please update your question with details of the new error (which you didn't mention before) and clarify when it errors and when it "hangs temporarily" in the way you originally described. Also details of what the service does (e.g. does it do IO; call another service or database; use COM interop; etc).

Answer (score 0):

By default the threadpool creates 8 threads and adds only two threads per second thereafter. When you fire up a raft of workers at the same time, WCF balks because the threads don't start quickly enough.

This is the solution that works nicely for me, call AdjustThreads whenever you're going to fire up lots of threads:

```
    Imports NLog
    Public Module AdjustThreads_

    Private _Logger As Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger
    Private _MaxWorkers As Integer = 16
    Private _MaxCompletions As Integer = 16
    Public Sub AdjustThreads()
        Dim minworkerthreads As Integer = 0
        Dim maxworkerthreads As Integer = 0
        Dim mincompletionthreads As Integer = 0
        Dim maxcompletionthreads As Integer = 0
        Dim activeworkerthreads As Integer = 0
        Dim activecompletionthreads As Integer = 0
        Threading.ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(minworkerthreads, mincompletionthreads)
        Threading.ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(maxworkerthreads, maxcompletionthreads)
        Threading.ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(activeworkerthreads, activecompletionthreads)
        Dim workers As Integer = maxworkerthreads - activeworkerthreads
        Dim completions As Integer = maxcompletionthreads - activecompletionthreads
        If workers > _MaxWorkers Then
            _MaxWorkers = _MaxWorkers
        End If
        If completions > _MaxCompletions Then
            _MaxCompletions = completions
        End If
        ' If current is (initially) 8, new threads only start twice a second.
        ' So, kick off a minimum of 16 and always increase by 50%
        Dim needworkers As Integer = _MaxWorkers * 3 \ 2
        Dim needcompletions As Integer = _MaxCompletions * 3 \ 2

        If needworkers > minworkerthreads OrElse
           needcompletions > mincompletionthreads Then
            _Logger.Info("Threadpool increasing workers to {0}, completions to {1}",
                         needworkers, needcompletions)
            Threading.ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(needworkers, needcompletions)
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

(damn editor keeps making 'End Module' fall out of the code, if someone could fix it?)